# Should the title be part of the nav element

Tags: html, css

Should I put the title of my page within the nav element if it will be on the same line? Or should the title be placed above the `<nav>` ?

```
TITLE OF PAGE               HOME BLOG PAGE1 PAGE2
```

code

```
<nav>

  <h1>TITLE OF PAGE</h1>

  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
  </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: You can do it either way. It would be easier to place it within your `nav `especially if you want to be able to select it to jump back home

Comment: If the `<h1>` is also for navigation, it would make sense, but since `<h1>` is (in part) for identifying the title of the page, it doesn't make much sense to have it in a navigation section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The title should be outside of the nav tag. Nav tags are meant to contain navigation links. Since your title isn't a navigation link, it really shouldn't be in there. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav for a description of the nav tag.

Comment: Unfortunately SO won't let me accept this as an answer.

Comment: There's a period of time between when you ask a question and when you're allowed to accept an answer. I'm not quite sure what it is though. So, just wait a while and you'll be able to accept it. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer is wrong. Refer to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/6925

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-nav-element) desciption, `nav` is not designed for this purpose but it may contain the navbar title **NOT** the page title. For example, consider this example from that link:

```html
<nav>
    <h1>Navigation</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="articles.html">Index of all articles</a></li>
        <li><a href="today.html">Things sheeple need to wake up for today</a></li>
        <li><a href="successes.html">Sheeple we have managed to wake</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

What BurningLights said above is correct, if it isn't part of the `nav` then it shouldn't be in.

I put together (quickly so may not be the best) a jsfiddle of the navigation bar. I want my logo to be selectable and to navigate the user back to the home screen, therefore, having the logo within my nav works for me.

https://jsfiddle.net/cbq5my61/

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do this, but when building a website you must also look from an SEO point of view. Your website must be semantically correct too.

It helps the crawlers and indexing site and building sitemap becomes more meaningful.

`nav` is used to contain **navigtaion menus**

You should use `header` tag for

- Site Title
- Site Logo
- Site headers

Answer (score 0):

You could optionally have your title contained in `nav` as the home link. Otherwise, it should be kept outside of the `nav` tag as it is not considered a nav link. This is for both SEO and better semantics. This doesn't mean that the navigation links can't flow to the right of the title, though.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, but the nav links won't align vertically with the title. Unfortunately I can't ask another question for 90 minutes.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I had to put a padding/margin of 0 to fix the vertical alignment issue.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it makes sense, you can put the heading inside the nav element. That means if the heading introduces the navigation (also the whole page can be a large navigation so it can be even an h1), it is ok to put the heading inside.

However, if the heading is something general - for example the name of the article below or the name of the whole site, it shouldn't be inside the nav element and I recommend to use something like this:

```
<header>
    <h1>Page title</h1>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="something">FOO</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav> 
</header>
```

For more information, see:
https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/nav